# How to get file's local absolute path during upload in Odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, path, odoo, odoo-13

I am using Odoo13 Enterprise Edition
I have a function like this:

```
def uploadImage(self, uploadImageRequest, isLocalFile=True): 
        uploadInfo = self.__createUploadImage(uploadImageRequest)
        self.__uploadOssObject(uploadImageRequest.filePath, uploadInfo['UploadAddress']['FileName'], uploadInfo, None)
        return uploadInfo['ImageId'], uploadInfo['ImageURL']
```

So I need to pass a filePath as variable which is a Char like "C:\Users\example\Desktop\example.jpg"

Here I decided to use a TransientModel to finish the upload, but it seems really inconvinient for users to copy and paste the path. 
I wonder how I can enable users to select the local file just like uploading a binary file, or how can I get the file's local absolute related to a binary field?

Answer (score 0):

To Get the **Absolute path** you can try this way,

```
import os
dir_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
relative_path = "data/text_file.txt"
absolute_path = os.path.join(dir_name, relative_path)
```

Thanks